# Window in Mono stuck in loading mode

Tags: winforms, f#, mono, f#-interactive, f#-3.0

I am writing a GUI program in F# with Visual Studio Code on my Macbook. When I run the code, I am stuck with a blank window with the wheel spinning. I am unable to close the window. I read in an article that it will take about 5 - 8 minutes for it to run with subsequent ones running faster. But I am always stuck and don't know what to do.

Here is my code:

```
#r "System.Windows.Forms";;
open System;;
open System.Windows.Forms;;
open System.Drawing;;

let form = new Form(Width = 400, Height = 300, Visible = true, Text = "Hello World");;
form.TopMost <- false;;
form.Click.Add (fun _ -> form.Text <- sprintf "form clicked at %i"   DateTime.Now.Ticks)
form.Show();
```

I get this in my log.

> Referenced '/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.4.2/lib/mono/4.5-api/System.Windows.Forms.dll' (file may be locked by F# Interactive process)

Comment: Can't find the duplicate but you need to call `Application.Run`

Answer (score 2):

From the `#r` in your code, I assume you are trying to run the code from F# Interactive.

You can create Windows Forms user interfaces from F# Interactive interactively, but on mono, this has some performance overhead, so it is not enabled by default. To allow that, you need to pass the `--gui` flag to F# interactive. (I know you can set this as an option somewhere in F# options in Xamarin Studio, but I'm not sure about other editors.)

Comment: please give me a sample code using the    --gui flag

Comment: Your code should work as is, when you turn on the `--gui` mode.

Comment: I don't know how to turn it on. Am still stuck! Tell me how to

Comment: am using visual studio code on a MacBook pro running OS X El Capitan 10.11.8.